# VB6: How can I get the amount of bytes that send via winsock?

Tags: tcp, vb6, winsock

How I can get the amount of bytes that had been sent via winsock through TCP connection?

Answer (score 0):

It's simply the return value of send().
For more information about send or Winsock in general look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms740149%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Question:

1. Do you want to know how many bytes were sent with a single .SendData() call?
2. Or do you want to know how many bytes were sent throughout the lifetime of your program running?

#### Question 1.

Several options:

1. You can just calculate the length of the data you're sending. It's very easy if it's a string: Len(DataBeingSent) will give you the number of bytes. Tell us what you're sending or show us some code.
2. You can keep track using a form-scope variable, but this is a pretty poor way to do it in my opinion unless it is for question **#2** above.

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Private lonBytesSent As Long

   Private Sub Winsock1_Connect()
     Dim strData As String

     strData = "This example uses a string but will work with any type being sent."
     ' Reset the number of bytes sent from any previous packets.
     lonBytesSent = 0
     Winsock1.SendData strData
   End Sub

   Private Sub Winsock1_SendComplete()
     MsgBox CStr(lonBytesSent) & " byte(s) sent on last transmission.", vbInformation
   End Sub

   Private Sub Winsock1_SendProgress(ByVal bytesSent As Long, ByVal bytesRemaining As Long)
     lonBytesSent = lonBytesSent + bytesSent
   End Sub
   ```

#### Question 2.

If this is the case, the above code will work just remove the `lonBytesSent = 0` before the `.SendData()` call. You may want to use a bigger data type than a `Long` if you will be sending a lot of data.